# How haproxy ddos protection works

Tags: haproxy, ddos

From the documentation of haproxy, it says that it has ddos protection.
Can anybody explain how it works ? It is enabled out of the box, or you need to configure it? I did not find much in the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

Haproxy docs doesn't explain you how to enable DDOS protection, because there is no 'ON/OFF' switch for this. Instead, Haproxy provided with tool-set to configure list of filtering rules. Here is a blog entry explains common DDOS mitigation patterns http://blog.haproxy.com/2012/02/27/use-a-load-balancer-as-a-first-row-of-defense-against-ddos/